# upload file to google SharedDrive from shell

Tags: google-drive-api

I use the following cmd to upload the file to google drive, and it's working when the path is on my personal google drive folder, but not on SharedDrive.
gdrive upload --name fileName -p xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx.img

I searched on google and found I need to set supportsalldrives=true. But I don't find how to set supportsalldrives=true on shell cmd.

Comment: gdrive upload --name fileName --supportsAllDrives -p xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx.img

Comment: @NIKUNJ KOTHIYA
Thanks for the reply, unfortunately, it's still not working, it says No valid arguments given, use 'gdrive help' to see available commands.

This is what I've tried.
gdrive upload --name xxxxx.apk --supportsAllDrives -p 1obPye2NiJSwWp3FDNRCbY805Mp8_tAwL ../xxxxxx.apk

Comment: @NIKUNJKOTHIYA Normally, how you know which options you can add in cmd I found this https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive
But I don't find --supportsAllDrives can be used in cmd. Where I can find the options? Many Thanks